# Wordpress woocommerce product categories

Tags: php, wordpress

For the last couple of hours i am struggling to figure out how to remove the categories ans sub categories that are displayed next to each product in a wordpress shop page. I have tried multiple sourccodes but the only one that seems to have some effect is the foollowing:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

After i added this code all the subcategories when i click on a single product are removed, the problem though is that the categories still remain in the shop page where all the products are shown in general

Is there anything else i can use that will hide/remove the categories from all the pages of my website? Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in regard

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, these settings can be controlled from woocommerce -> settings -> display.  [See here](https://imgur.com/a/yMyAW)

Comment: I have already tried that and i haven t found anything in the settings